# Which car rental companies in Northern Cyprus permit you to drive to the Republic?

Tags: paperwork, car-rentals, borders, permits, northern-cyprus

Essentially what the question says: I'm looking to rent a car in Northern Cyprus, and occasionally take it across the border to the Republic.

I know few companies will issue the necessary cross-border permit.

Which ones do?

Comment: Pacific Rentals [claims](https://www.pacific-rentals.com/border-crossing.asp) " If on the other hand you rent your car in the North of Cyprus you are not allowed to take it across the border.  If the car is your own you are allowed to take it across the border. ".

Comment: @chx I've been told there are a few companies that issue a permit to exit North Cyprus with the car - then you can buy insurance from the Republic police.

Answer (score 5):

The North Cypriot companies I've found allowing cross-border travel are Esentepe Brisk (what I ended up going for) Oscars and Baspinar.

You buy an EU Cypriot insurance at the border for €25 lasting a month.

Comment: I thought it unusual that you hadn't answered your own query; at this you have now, so I'll delete :)